# How to visualise errors from doPost(e)?

Tags: google-apps-script, error-logging

I have been attempting to find a method to log any errors that occur after a doPost(e) method executes with Apps Script (using JS). The [previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772207/debug-a-google-apps-script-which-is-triggered-by-post-request) regarding this topic mentioned StackDriver logging with reference to the old editor provided by Google. However, how do I access a similar function with the new editor?

For some more context, if I execute functions from script editor, the Google Sheet they are editing, or through a trigger, I am able to view the errors through the Execution Log tab. But for any calls made through doPost, I am unable to view the causes of error. How do I log these errors?

Edit: I believe there might be a slight misunderstanding. The programmed doPost(e) takes user input from a Telegram bot and responds accordingly. Till date, the bot has been functioning as designed; however, for future debugging I wish to be able to somehow see any caused errors. This would provide more information than simply a "Failed" in the execution log. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using JS to log errors from a doPost(e)?  doPost(e) is a server side endpoint.  How about just doing `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` on the very first line after the function declaration.

Comment: Executing the doPost(e) from a script editor is a bad idea unless you are providing the event object and I'm guessing since you're asking this question that you not providing the event object so it's a rather pointless exercise.

Comment: @Cooper Ok I believe there might be room for some more clarity here. Currently, the doPost(e) collects its data based on user input to a Telegram bot. However, when errors occur with the doPost(e) after being called from Telegram, and because it is a server side endpoint and error logging, I am unable to diagnose the issue myself. As such, I'm trying to find a way to log these errors to work out why the error is occurring (for reference, it isn't a usual error, it occurs intermittently from time to time).

Comment: To keep it short, I'm trying to find a good way to debug an issue and get some actual information on the code rather than just knowing it failed.

Comment: You say `and because it is a server side endpoint and error logging, I am unable to diagnose the issue myself.` why not?

Comment: And that is the part I am unaware of why I can't view them. I had previously tried a try-catch with both console.log and Logger.log (accompanied with a deliberate error from the bot), but neither showed any errors under Cloud Logs (yet the execution was still listed as failed).

Comment: I'm trying to learn here myself haha. I'm not too used to working with JS, let alone Apps Scripts. So thank you for taking the time to help! Hopefully, I can understand and work it out.

Comment: Have you looked in executions?

Answer (score 1):

### [Apps Script Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging)

> Note:
>
> [Error Reporting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#error_reporting) interface in the Developer Console is pretty much similar with option 2 so I will not provide any further example.

---

**Sample WebApp Code:**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  console.log(params);
}
```

**Sample Request:**

```
https://script.google.com/..../exec?username=sample2&password=1234
```

### Option1: Check the built-in [Apps Script execution log](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#basic_logging)

1. You can check the logs when you open your script and go to `Execution tab`

[image]

2. You can also check the logs in `https://script.google.com/home/executions`

[image]

### Option2: Using [Cloud Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#cloud_logging) interface in the Developer Console

- Assuiming you already attached a standard GCP project with your script project

You can [view Cloud logs and error reports in the Google Cloud Platform console](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#viewing_cloud_logs_and_error_reports_in_the_google_cloud_platform_console)

- Under Log Fields -> Select Apps Script Function
- It will display the results under Query Results Tab

[image]